# sorting not working in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my script :

```
function getAllExperiences(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var perPage = 10
        var page = req.params.page || 1
        var type = req.body.type;
        var sortAs = req.body.sortAs;
        Experiences
            .find({status:'live'})
            .sort({type:sortAs})//,{duration:durationValue}
            .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
            .limit(perPage)
            .exec(function(err, results) {
                Experiences.count().exec(function(err, count) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        reject(err);
                    }else{
                        var obj = 
                        {
                            experiences: results,
                            current: page,
                            pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
                        };
                        resolve(obj);
                    }
                })
            })
    });
}
```

i am sorting according. **price**, **duration**, **ratings**
when i set

```
var type = 'price';
var sortAs = -1;
```

if i set

```
var type = 'price';
var sortAs = 1;
```

if i set

```
var type = 'duration';
var sortAs = -1;
```

or

```
var type = 'duration';
var sortAs = 1;
```

All condition gives me same result. i thing type is not accepting. what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getAllExperiences(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var perPage = 10
        var page = req.params.page || 1
        var type = req.body.type;
        var sortAs = Number(req.body.sortAs);
        var sort = {};
        sort[type] = sortAs;
        Experiences
            .find({status:'live'})
            .sort(sort)//,{duration:durationValue}
            .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
            .limit(perPage)
            .exec(function(err, results) {
                Experiences.count().exec(function(err, count) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        reject(err);
                    }else{
                        var obj = 
                        {
                            experiences: results,
                            current: page,
                            pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
                        };
                        resolve(obj);
                    }
                })
            })
    });
}
```

Comment: This is best solution: use es6 variable to create dynamic object key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422288/7526159

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is

```
{ type: sortAs }
```

where type is being used as object key, what you should do is

```
{ [type]: sortAs }
```

Here type is being used as variable to create dynamic key for the object. thus this will create.

```
{duration: "-1"}
```

Following code should work for you.

```
function getAllExperiences(){
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    var perPage = 10
    var page = req.params.page || 1
    var type = req.body.type;
    var sortAs = req.body.sortAs;
    Experiences
        .find({status:'live'})
        .sort({ [type] : sortAs })//, using es6 for generating dynamic property
        .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .exec(function(err, results) {
            Experiences.count().exec(function(err, count) {
                if (err)
                {
                    reject(err);
                }else{
                    var obj = 
                    {
                        experiences: results,
                        current: page,
                        pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
                    };
                    resolve(obj);
                }
            })
        })
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `.sort({type:sortAs})//,{duration:durationValue}` to

```
var sortDefinition = {};
sortDefinition[type] = sortAs;

//then in pipeline
.sort(sortDefinition)
```

Because in your example it will always try to sort by field with name `type`since it's a key name in that code.